# Collection reduce and sum by key

Tags: laravel, collections

I have a Collection like:

```
#items: array:2 [
    0 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {
      #items: array:1 [
        1 => 3
      ]
    }
    1 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {
      #items: array:2 [
        1 => 1
        3 => 2
      ]
    }
    2 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {
      #items: array:2 [
        1 => 2
        2 => 2
      ]
    }
  ]
```

and I somehow want to reduce this Collection only to one entry with `sum` by key.
Result should look like:

```
#items: array:1 [
    0 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {
      #items: array:2 [
        1 => 5
        2 => 2
        3 => 2
      ]
    }
  ]
```

How can I achieve this with Laravel?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum values from associative array if there is the same key in php laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63976299/how-to-sum-values-from-associative-array-if-there-is-the-same-key-in-php-laravel)

Comment: Not exactly, as it returns only first key with sum for everything and ignores multiple keys. Output is: 1 => 9

Comment: Got the result you wanted, but key 1 should have 6 as a value in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a similar result:

```
$keys = $collection->map->keys()   // collection of collection of keys
                   ->flatten()     // collection of keys (with duplicates, unsorted)
                   ->unique()      // collection of keys (no duplicates, unsorted)
                   ->sort()        // collection of keys (no duplicates, sorted)
                                   // colleciton of [key => sum of values from original collection by key]
                   ->mapWithKeys(fn($item) => [$item => $collection->sum($item)]);
```

`dump($keys);` returns:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {
  #items: array:3 [
    1 => 6
    2 => 2
    3 => 2
  ]
}
```

`dump([$keys]);` returns:

```
array:1 [
  0 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {
    #items: array:3 [
      1 => 6
      2 => 2
      3 => 2
    ]
  }
]
```